# Getting ">>>" instead of the string I programmed

Tags: python

*Hi, I am using Python 3 and I was trying the "Comma code" program from "Automate the boring stuff with Python" (so you can guess I am pretty new to it).
I wanted to print "your list is empty" if the list the user inputs is empty, but instead I am getting "your list is >>>". Why?
Below you can see the code:*

```py
def commaCode(passedList):

    for i in (passedList):
        if len(passedList)==0:
            print('empty')
        elif passedList.index(i)<len(passedList)-1:
            print(str(i),end=', ')
        else:
            print ('and ' + (passedList[-1]))


passedList=list(input('insert a list:'))
print('you created the list', end=' ')
print(passedList)
print('your list is', end=' ')
commaCode(passedList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `commaCode` doesn't print anything, and you see the `>>>` prompt.

When the list is empty, `for i in passedList` does nothing, and the `print('empty')` is not encountered.

That's fixed with

```
def commaCode(passedList):
    if not passedList:
        print("empty")
        return

    for i in passedList:
        if passedList.index(i) < len(passedList) - 1:
            print(str(i), end=", ")
        else:
            print("and " + (passedList[-1]))
```

but there's still another unrelated bug you can encounter by entering the list `aabaa`. :)

Comment: does that mean an empty list has no length then? I thought the length of an empty list to be 0

Comment: ok, I think I do not understand why the for loop is not working if the list is empty

Comment: Because there's nothing to loop over! What would a for loop do for an empty list, in your opinion? What would `i` be in `for i in passedList`?

Answer (score 0):

If the passed list is empty, the loop is never entered. You need your `print('empty')` statement *outside* the loop.

```
def commaCode(passedList):

    if not passedList:
        print('empty')
        return

    for i, char in enumerate(passedList):
        if i < len(passedList) - 1:
            print(char, end=', ')
        else:
            print('and ' + char)
```

Comment: Why are you using return only in the if condition and not in the for loop?